# I can't install the library grpcio

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, grpc

When I'm install a dialogflow a grpcio it crashes when running...

**What version of gRPC and what language I'm using?**

I'm install a version:

- grpcio==1.30.0
- python==3.6.9

**Output error:**

```
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-hpq5jtn0/grpcio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-48xyxihh-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-hpq5jtn0/grpcio/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to solve. Problem is with setuptools. Downgrade it to 49.6.0 and try installing it will work.

```py
pip install setuptools==49.6.0
```

ref: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/24037

Comment: I'm trying to install tensorflow 1.15, and my install keeps failing while installing tf's grpcio dependency...unfortunately charging the setup tools version did not fix this for me.

Comment: This was the only answer to this problem that I found that worked for me.