# pip3 install grpcio fails on Raspberri Pi 3 (Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, raspberry-pi, grpc

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2.
With the help of Raspberry Imager, I flashed a clean install of
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS    -   5.4.0-1045-raspi.

I now want to run a python server application, using gRPC.
Therefore I installed pip with:

> sudo apt-get install pip

resulting in the following Python pacages on my Pi:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

If I now try to install grpcio with the help of

> sudo pip3 install grpcio

the Raspberry Pi literally takes half a day, trying to:

> Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ...

before ultimately failing that with the error messages pasted here: https://pastebin.com/8WeQX1JX

What am I doing wrong and how can I get gRPC to run within python on my Raspberry.
I expected that with a clean install of Ubuntu Server this would work out-of-the-box and also not take the Pi half a day to generate me this lovely error message =/

Comment: Looks like missing dependency, have a try for `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`

Comment: Just tried this and it does not solve the problem. This gets the same result and also pip3 should take care or alert because of missing dependencies, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Facing the same issue, were you able to resolve this in the mean time?

Comment: seems like a common issue:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56357794/unable-to-install-grpcio-using-pip-install-grpcio  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63810848/i-cant-install-the-library-grpcio